# Getting columns of a a check constraint

Tags: sql-server

I use the following script to get check constraints and its related columns

```
select 
    col.[name] as column_name,
    con.[definition],    
    con.[name] as constraint_name
from sys.check_constraints con
    left outer join sys.objects t
        on con.parent_object_id = t.object_id
    left outer join sys.all_columns col
        on con.parent_column_id = col.column_id
        and con.parent_object_id = col.object_id
```

But I receive `"NULL"` when the check expression concerns with 2 or more different columns, e.g in a table having more than 2 columns and the check constraints looking like this `([col1] <> [col2])` or `([col1] < 0 and [col2] = 0)`.

I'd want to replace `"Null"` returned in the above script  with a string e.g `"col1, col2"`

Answer (score 0):

We can improve on the query by returning the level of constraint instead of constraint . Of course, this will return the column name for column-level constraints only. For table-level constraints `NULL` will be returned.

> **column_name** - name of the column for column-level check constraints, null for table-level check constraints

```
SELECT 
  cc.name AS 'Constraint',
  cc.is_disabled AS 'Disabled?',
  CASE WHEN cc.parent_column_id = 0 THEN 'Table-level' ELSE 'Column-level' END AS 'Table/Column',
  o.name AS 'Table',
  ISNULL(ac.name, '(n/a)') AS 'Column',
  cc.Definition AS 'Constraint Definition'
FROM sys.check_constraints cc
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.objects o ON cc.parent_object_id = o.object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.all_columns ac ON cc.parent_column_id = ac.column_id AND cc.parent_object_id = ac.object_id;

+-----------------+-------------+----------------+----------------+----------+----------------------------------------+
| Constraint      | Disabled?   | Table/Column   | Table          | Column   | Constraint Definition                  |
|-----------------+-------------+----------------+----------------+----------+----------------------------------------|
| chkPrice        | 0           | Column-level   | ConstraintTest | Price    | ([Price]>(0))                          |
| chkValidEndDate | 0           | Table-level    | ConstraintTest | (n/a)    | ([EndDate]>=[StartDate])               |
| chkTeamSize     | 0           | Column-level   | ConstraintTest | TeamSize | ([TeamSize]>=(5) AND [TeamSize]<=(20)) |
| chkJobTitle     | 0           | Column-level   | Occupation     | JobTitle | ([JobTitle]<>'Digital Nomad')          |
+-----------------+-------------+----------------+----------------+----------+----------------------------------------+
```